# Convert Pandas DF with timestamp string to local datetime without tz

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, localtime

I have DataFrame column with string timestamp and I want to convert it to local datetime without time zone.

```
df = {'id' : [1, 2, 3],
      'timestamp' : ['2019-07-01T21:30:20Z', '2019-07-02T21:30:20Z', '2019-07-03T21:30:20Z']}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['id','timestamp'])
```

My code:

```
df['timestamp'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",
  errors='ignore')).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Europe/Prague'))
```

This works for example above but not for example below.
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp

```
df = {'id' : [1, 2, 3],
      'timestamp' : ['2019-07-01T21:30:20Z', '2999-12-31T21:30:20Z', '9999-12-30T21:30:20Z']}
```

It is problem with 2999-12-31T21:30:20Z or 9999-12-30T21:30:20Z. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So the max timestamp pandas can hold is `'2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807'` (see https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations). Therefore both the second and third timestamps are the issues.

As for the fix if you need those dates I am unsure if I can help you. However you can drop them by changing the errors parameter.

I also got rid of some of the functions you called as they don't need to be there.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 3], 
                   'timestamp' : ['2019-07-01T21:30:20Z', 
                                  '2999-12-31T21:30:20Z', 
                                  '9999-12-30T21:30:20Z']})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], 
                                 format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", errors='coerce', utc=True)

df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Prague')
```

`df.dropna()` if you need to drop the `NaT` values

Comment: Thank you for your answer and correcting my code. Unfortunately I can not drop those dates so I have to find some solution, if it exists.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob maybe this is what you're looking for?